# Getting 'Cart cannot be loaded' error in Prestashop in custom Payment Module

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules, prestashop-helper-classes

This is where I'm validating the order. But all the fields of cart object are null.

```
public function createOrder(){
        $cart = $this->context->cart;
        $total = (float)$cart->getOrderTotal(true, Cart::BOTH);
        $customer = new Customer($cart->id_customer);
        $this->module->validateOrder($cart->id, Configuration::get('PS_OS_PAYMENT'), $total, $this->module->displayName, null, array(), $this->context->currency->id, false, $customer->secure_key);
        Tools::redirect($this->context->link->getPageLink('order-confirmation', Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED'), $this->context->language->id, 'id_cart='.$cart->id.'&id_module='.$this->module->id.'&id_order='.$this->module->currentOrder.'&key='.$customer->secure_key));
    }
```

How to fix this? Any help is appreciated.

I am expecting it to validate the order and redirect on order confirmation page.

Comment: Hi, can you add some context ? How and from where are you calling this function ? Did you follow these instructions to create your payment module  ? https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/1.7/modules/payment/

Comment: @ébewè I have two front controllers, I make request to payment gateway from 'payment.php', on success it redirects to 'validate.php?mtid=xxxxx' where I validate the transaction, and then run validateOrder(), but it throws that error. the values of the cart object are null. Is it possible that its because the session gets destroyed when user leaves to another url for payment hence could not access cart data session

Comment: It could be, but it shouldn't be destroyed. Did you try replacing $this->context by Context::getContext() ?